# Php: How to calculate Adler32 checksum for zip?

Tags: php, apache-flex, compression, zip, adler32

I'm using a combination of Paul Duncans php ZipStream (http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/) on the server side, for on-the-fly creation of zips, and Fzip (http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/) on the Flex/Air client side.

Works fine in Air, but when running Flex in browser, the zip needs to include a Adler32 checksum in the header for FZip to be read.

How can I calculate an Adler32 checksum for the zip in php?

The ZipStream core functions, using gzdeflate for compression, can be seen below.

Regards / Jonas

```
function add_file($name, $data, $opt = array(), $deflateLevel=0) {
    # compress data

    $zdata = gzdeflate($data, $deflateLevel);

    # calculate header attributes

    $crc  = crc32($data);
    $zlen = strlen($zdata);
    $len  = strlen($data);
    $meth = 0x08;

    # send file header
    $this->add_file_header($name, $opt, $meth, $crc, $zlen, $len);

    # print data
    $this->send($zdata);
}

private function add_file_header($name, $opt, $meth, $crc, $zlen, $len) {
    # strip leading slashes from file name
    # (fixes bug in windows archive viewer)
    $name = preg_replace('/^\\/+/', '', $name);

    # calculate name length
    $nlen = strlen($name);

    # create dos timestamp
    $opt['time'] = $opt['time'] ? $opt['time'] : time();
    $dts = $this->dostime($opt['time']);

    # build file header
    $fields = array(            # (from V.A of APPNOTE.TXT)
    array('V', 0x04034b50),     # local file header signature
    array('v', (6 << 8) + 3),   # version needed to extract
    array('v', 0x00),           # general purpose bit flag
    array('v', $meth),          # compresion method (deflate or store)
    array('V', $dts),           # dos timestamp
    array('V', $crc),           # crc32 of data
    array('V', $zlen),          # compressed data length
    array('V', $len),           # uncompressed data length
    array('v', $nlen),          # filename length
    array('v', 0),              # extra data len
    );

    # pack fields and calculate "total" length
    $ret = $this->pack_fields($fields);
    $cdr_len = strlen($ret) + $nlen + $zlen;

    # print header and filename
    $this->send($ret . $name);

    # add to central directory record and increment offset
    $this->add_to_cdr($name, $opt, $meth, $crc, $zlen, $len, $cdr_len);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanslated from the [example implementation in the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32#Example_implementation):

```
define('MOD_ADLER', 65521);

function adler32($data) {
    $a = 1; $b = 0; $len = strlen($data);
    for ($index = 0; $index < $len; ++$index) {
        $a = ($a + $data[$index]) % MOD_ADLER;
        $b = ($b + $a) % MOD_ADLER;
    }
    return ($b << 16) | $a;
}
```

And to convert that integer value to bytes:

```
pack('H*', $checksum);
```

Comment: Thanx, Gumbo!
I'll test it!

Jonas

Answer (score 2):

For PHP 5 >= 5.1.2 you can use the [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function which returns a hex string representation of the crc:

```
$dataStr = "abc";
$crcStr = hash('adler32', $dataStr);
```

UPDATE: There was a [bug in hash until mid 2009](http://bugs.php.net/48284) where the byte order was around the wrong way. The bug appears to fixed in [5.2.11](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.11) and 5.3.0 onwards. But for earlier versions the byte order of the result will need to be swapped.

UPDATE 2: Here's a wrapper function (and a test) which could be used to work around that bug:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

function hash_adler32_wrapper($data) {
    $digHexStr = hash("adler32", $data);

    // If version is better than 5.2.11 no further action necessary
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.2.11', '>=')) {
        return $digHexStr;
    }

    // Workaround #48284 by swapping byte order
    $boFixed = array();
    $boFixed[0] = $digHexStr[6];
    $boFixed[1] = $digHexStr[7];
    $boFixed[2] = $digHexStr[4];
    $boFixed[3] = $digHexStr[5];
    $boFixed[4] = $digHexStr[2];
    $boFixed[5] = $digHexStr[3];
    $boFixed[6] = $digHexStr[0];
    $boFixed[7] = $digHexStr[1];

    return implode("", $boFixed);
}

// Test fixture, plus expected output generated using the adler32 from zlib
$data_in = "abc";
$expected_out = 0x024d0127;

// PHP's hash function returns a hex hash value as a string so hexdec used to
// convert to number
$hash_out = hexdec(hash("adler32", $data_in));

// Get value via the wrapper function
$wrapper_out = hexdec(hash_adler32_wrapper($data_in));

printf("data_in:          %s\n", $data_in);
printf("expected_out:     0x%08x\n", $expected_out);
printf("builtin hash out: 0x%08x, %s\n", $hash_out,
        ($hash_out == $expected_out)? "OK" : "NOT OK");
printf("wrapper func out: 0x%08x, %s\n", $wrapper_out,
        ($wrapper_out == $expected_out)? "OK" : "NOT OK");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Gumbo's solution is almost perfect - but if the parameter is a string instead of an array of bytes, you'll need to use ord() to get the ascii code of the character to process. Like this:

```
function adler32($data) {
    $a = 1; $b = 0; $len = strlen($data);
    for ($index = 0; $index < $len; ++$index) {
        $a = ($a + ord($data[$index])) % 65521;
        $b = ($b + $a) % 65521;
    }
    return ($b << 16) | $a;
}
```